# Referring to 'this' in a function in Main in AnyLogic

Tags: anylogic

I have a function in Main called `myFunction` and returns a Boolean:

```
if(this instanceof MyAgent) 
    return true;
else;
    return false;
```

This function is called in a process block in `FactoryAgent`, and it simply checks whether the agent that flows through the process block is of type `MyAgent`. However, when I call this function I get the following error:
`Description: Incompatible conditional operand types Main and FactoryAgent.`

Inputting `this instanceof MyAgent` directly in the `On enter` field of the process block works. How can I correctly refer to `this` in a function in `Main`?

Answer (score 0):

this is wrong... the keyword "this" refers to the agent in which you call a function..

If you have a process block in main, this "refers" to main, if you use it in your agent FactoryAgent, "this" refers to FactoryAgent... this means that it will always return false, because "this" is never an instance of MyAgent

Instead you should use the local variable "agent" and change all this to

```
if(agent instanceof MyAgent) 
    return true;
else;
    return false;
```

if you want to call this function anywhere, you need to call it with an argument which is the agent that is flowing through the process. If it can be many types of agents, then the argument will be of type Agent, or maybe of type Object.

If you don't know what it means for your function to have an argument, or if you don't know that you can use a local variable called agent, I can explain it, but these are terms that are so fundamental, that I will assume you know